# How do I get the MAC address using vxWorks6.8 API in real-time process?

Tags: vxworks

I know endFindByName() and muxIoctl(),but these two functions depend on "muxLib.h" and END_OBJ depend on "end.h".These two header files only be used in kernel mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but try to use `ioctl()` with `SIOCGIFLLADDR`:

```
sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

ioctl (sock, SIOCGIFLLADDR, &ifr);

close (sock);
```

in `ifr.ifr_ifru.ifru_addr` is your mac.

Comment: First of all,thank you for your answer.But I can't get any information about `SIOCGIFLLADDR`.I know `ioctl()` is used in Linux,and i know VxWorks is compatible with BSD.I can use `getifaddrs` to get information about network in vxworks6.8 RTP mode.I can get the right network card name and the right ip address ,but i cant get the right mac address.I am working hard on my English . Thank you.

Comment: I am using VxWorks7 and have no experience in 6.8. In VxWorks7 the definition is given in "ipioctl.h". Maybe that helps.

Comment: Oh,thank you so much.I get the correct mac address(link level address).I couldn't have done it without you.Thank you again.